# Symbolic versus numeric sum (is there an inconsistency?)

Tags: summation

Something seems to have gone awry with the analytic sum (v9.0.1).  Here I insert specific values:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n/2}] /. {a -> 4.2, b -> 1.2, n -> 3}
```

returns `92.232`.

```
With[{a = 4.2, b = 1.2, n = 3}, Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n/2}]]
```

returns `63.504`

Did I do something wrong? or is the analytic sum not quite right?  Bug, perhaps?  Maybe `n` is assumed integer in the first case?

Comment: try with even n. i suspect that n/2 is a problem for the analytic soluton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the symbolic `Sum` is assuming `n/2 ∈ Integers && n >= 2`. We can see this with the option `GenerateConditions -> True`:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n/2}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[1/2 a^n (((a + b)/a)^n - (-1 + b/a)^n), 
>   n/2 ∈ Integers && n >= 2]
> ```

A fix is to take the floor of `n/2`:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, Floor[n/2]},
  GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[(* messy expression *), 
>   Floor[n/2] >= 1 && (a != b^2/a || Re[n] > 0) && Floor[n/2] ∈ Integers]
> ```

```
Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), 
  {k, 1, Floor[n/2]}] /. {a -> 4.2, b -> 1.2, n -> 3}
```

> ```
> 63.504
> ```

Comment: Nice. In your experience, does `GenerateConditions -> True` often prove useful as a first step for debugging in cases like this?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus, yes. Whenever I see something odd about `Sum`, this is what I try first.

Answer (score 3):

The only important variable here is n.

The first case, when n in undefined, is "symbolical summation". The second, when n is fixed in advance, is an ordinary summation. In the first case general "close form" answer is derived, then numerical value of n is substituted. In the second case explicit summation is performed from the very beginning.

Obviously, here symbolic summation fails. "Symbolic summation" actually is not a summation in the ordinary sense. You can read about these methods for example in the fantastic free [book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html). Symbolic summation, which is based on derivation and solving reccurence relations, seems failing here, as you can see comparing

```
(Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, 
             n/2}] /. {n -> 3}) // Simplify
```

> a^3 + 3 a b^2

and

```
Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1) /. {n -> 3, k -> 1}
```

> 3 a^2 b

(sum in this case has only single term).

Why symbolic summation fails is an interesting question and requires further investigation. It can be bug or it can simply be impossible to symbolically  account for n/2 condition.

Answer (score 2):

comment with figures..
The issue can be illustrated more simply looking at this:

```
 Sum[ i , {i, 1, n/2}]
 Sum[ i , {i, 1, 3/2}]
 Sum[ i , {i, 1, Floor[n/2]}] /. n -> 3
 Sum[ i , {i, 1, Ceiling[n/2]}] /. n -> 3
 Sum[ i , {i, 1, n/2}] /. n -> 3
```

> ```
>  1/8 n (2 + n)
>     1
>     1
>     3
>     15/8
> ```

```
 Show[{
  ListPlot[ 
     Table[ {n, Sum[ i , {i, 1, Ceiling[n/2]}]} /. n -> j , { j, 1, 10}] ,
         Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red],
  ListPlot[ 
     Table[ {n, Sum[ i , {i, 1, Floor[n/2]}]} /. n -> j , { j, 1, 10}] ,
         Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Green],
  ListPlot[ 
     Table[ {n, Sum[ i , {i, 1, n/2}]} /. n -> j , { j, 1, 10}] , 
         Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]}]
```

[image]

The case where you fail to specify if you want `Floor` or `Ceiling` is mathematically ambiguous, and you get some intermediate value.

Comment: It means that analytical (or "close form") answer has no meaning without additional information. So cannot be treated as a bug of Sum. Its a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I compared this with Maple 18.02, both on windows 7, 64 bit.
Maple symbolic and numerical both give the same result, which is 65.23200003. Maple symbolic result does not appear the same as Mathematica symbolic only result. Maple uses special function LegendreP in its symbolic result.

Compare: Maple symbolic only result:

```
restart;
r:=sum(binomial(n, 2*k - 1)*a^(n - 2*k + 1)* b^(2*k - 1), k=1..n/2);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
evalf(subs({a=4.2,b=1.2,n=3},r));
(*65.23200003*)
```

Mathematica symbolic result

```
 mma=Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k - 1] a^(n - 2 k + 1) b^(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  mma /. {a -> 4.2, b -> 1.2, n -> 3}
  (*92.232*)
```

Looking the both results for different `n`, they agree for odd `n` only. 
(actually for `n=2` Maple gives complex answer!)

```
maple = {1.2, 2.880000002*I, 65.23200003, 384.6528003, 2174.325120, 
    12032.95566, 65852.76052, 3.582293070*10^5}; (*from Maple worksheet*)
r = Table[{i, mma /. {a -> 4.2, b -> 1.2, n -> i}, maple[[i]]}, {i, 1, 8, 1}];
r = Insert[r, {"n", "Mathematica", "Maple"}, 1];
Grid[r, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My guess is that **Mathematica result is only valid for `n>2` and even `n`**, as Chip Hurst mentioned also above and also george2079 mentioned the even condition in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer returned depends on the order in which `ReplaceAll` is applied and how it impacts the upper limit of `Sum`.  In the first case above, the sum is performed first, producing the answer. 
        1/2 a^n (((a+b)/a)^n-(b/a-1)^n).
Evaluating this for `{a -> 4.2, b -> 1.2, n -> 3}` gives 92.232.  In the second case above, the substitution is performed before `Sum`. Hence, the upper limit `n/2` becomes 1.5, which is treated as 1, and only the first term in the `Sum` is computed.  Its value is 63.504.

Comment: As @george2079 commented, if n were an even integer, the results would be the same, for instance 384.653 for `n->4`

Comment: try putting `Ceiling[n/2]`  in both.. (cant test here)